# Placing the first 3 elements of a TreeMap in a TOAST ranked by their key, showing their values

Tags: java, android, treemap, android-toast

Alright, so I've got a sorted tree map by it's key. Key is an Integer, value is a String. I'm trying to make a Toast that will display the first 3 elements by their value. They're already ranked, I just want to show their names in the toast. I assume this is fairly easy, but I've tried lots of stuff that failed, so I'm grasping at straws here. Here is what it looks like.

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> sorted = new TreeMap<>(courses);

Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ,duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
```

I was thinking of a for loop to get the first 3 elements, but I also need to slap some nice text around the elements, so I'm out of ideas, probably because it's 3am here and I'm dead tired. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, the treemap is made of courses and points (it's a quiz app that helps you choose a college course). Picking a certain answer to a question awards you a point to a certain course. I need to place the 3 courses with the most points in a toast (Integer - points, String - Course name). Hope that helps.

Comment: You say you want to use the first three elements, but you also say you want the ones with the most points, and you show creating the TreeMap without any Comparator. These points appear to be in conflict.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first three values from the map, you can use:

```
sorted.entrySet().stream()                // stream the entries from the map
    .limit(3)                             // only take the first three
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)             // get the value from the entry
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));   // collect them in a comma-delimited list
```

The TreeMap by default will sort the entries from lowest to highest. To sort them from highest to lowest, create the TreeMap with a suitable Comparator:

```
// creating a TreeMap with a Comparator that compares integers in reverse order
TreeMap<Integer, String> sorted = new TreeMap<>((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b, a));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, but aren't Treemaps autosorted by their key values? I thought you only needed a comparator for special cases? Also, would you mind explaining the code you posted? I understand the first 2 lines but I get lost at the end.

Comment: @DanIonis They are autosorted -- from lowest to highest. If you want them sorted from highest to lowest, you need to specify. I'll add some explanation.

Comment: I actually didn't know about that, honestly it's my first time using Treemaps. Thanks, I'll look up on how to reverse the order.

Comment: @Dan Hopefully this is clear. Let me know if it isn't.

Comment: I understand it, thanks David. I've used Comparator.reverseOrder(), hopefully that's ok? Also, I assume my treemap is probably going to have the same keys in some places (it's very likely that the top 3 could all have the same keys). I can't find conclusive info that the treemap doesn't do same keys for some reason. If that's not allowed, what could I use instead? I don't care which 3 it picks, this is a minor project so I have room to make it spaghetti and non practical.

Comment: @DanIonis Sure, Comparator.reverseOrder() is fine, I just didn't remember the syntax off the top of my head so I used a lambda. A Map won't allow duplicates. If you need that, you might want a multimap, which there is a good implementation of in the Guava library, or perhaps just a PriorityQueue, which you can find in java.util.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215854/discussion-between-dan-ionis-and-david-conrad).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I could use some help.


So I'm using a TreeMultimap now, but the part where I'm limiting the map doesn't work now, well the "entrySet()" part of it. Any replacement for that?